# How to know each solaris zone is occupying how much disk space?

Tags: solaris

IF I use the df command, I can only see in the Solaris server how much disk space is being used up.  But I want to know how much diskspace a particular solaris zone is occupying

Answer (score 4):

The problem I found with these solutions is that they do not take into account directory inheritance.  Yes, you will find out how much "space" is under a certain directory.  But if you want to actually find out how much extra space a zone is taking, you have to go a different route.
Do a

```
zonecfg -z zonename info
```

where zonename is the name of the zone.  And look at each inherit-pkg-dir line.

```
inherit-pkgdir-dir:
      dir: /lib
inherit-pkgdir-dir:
      dir: /sbin
```

Any line that has inheritance is hard-linked to the zone.  So you will be double
counting against the global zone if you simply do a

```
du -sh /zonepath/zonename
```

Basically you have to count only the directories (excluding /proc, and maybe /tmp) that aren't listed in any `inherit-pkg-dir` lines.

```
cd /zonepath/zonename/root

du -sh /bin /dev /etc /home /kernel opt /system /var etc....
```

Answer (score 2):

try the du command

Comment: du of what path ? I have posted an answer where I show what path ot consider.

Comment: Ok. It is a bit scary though that I have to execute my du as root (sudo root, but root nonetheless)

Answer (score 2):

Yes - definitely su to root to do this.

I was able to run: /usr/xpg4/bin/du -sk -h -x /zonepath/zonename 
to get the space that was used in a UFS root partition of a zone.

For example, /usr/xpg4/bin/du -sk -h -x /zonepath/zonename
 
returned the following:  3.5G /zonepath/zonename

The -x option when evaluating file sizes, evaluates only those files that have the same device as the file specified by the file operand.

The -x operand only seems to work when calling du with this path:  /usr/xpg4/bin/du

This also worked to display the used space of the zfs attached drives in the zone!  We mounted one zfs lun to the path /zoneepath/zonename/data and running this matched the output of "zfs list" for the data file:

# /usr/xpg4/bin/du  -sk -h -x /zonepath/zoneneame/data
   11G /zonepath/zoneneame/data

If you run #/usr/xpg4/bin/du  -sk -h -x /zonepath/zoneneame
then you should get an overall total of the used space in the zone such as:
  53G /zonepath/zonename

It will not include NFS attached drives, nor will it include directories that root is not the owner of.

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Since I tried both John's solution and Pierre-Luc solution, what works for me is:

- list all the zone (from the global zone)

:

```
tcsh>zoneadm list -civ
  ID NAME             STATUS     PATH                           BRAND    IP
   0 global           running    /                              native   shared
   1 myZone1          running    /export/zones/myZone1          native   shared
   2 myZone2          running    /export/zones/myZone2          native   shared
```

- `du -sk` as root
  (since local zones are not readable from global zone, I had to `du -sk` them as root)

:

```
 tcsh>s du -sk /export/zones/myZone1  
 9930978 /export/zones/myZone1
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [Solaris Operating System Managing ZFS in Solaris 10 Containers](http://www.sun.com/software/solaris/howtoguides/zfshowto.jsp) the following command would give you the information you require.

```
zfs list
```

Comment: That gives me "no datasets available",, which is not exactly helpful.

Comment: Turns out I misread the question. My solution will absolutly not help you.

Answer (score 0):

If you install the zone on a zfs volume then you can use the zfs tools ("zfs list") to quickly see how much space has been used.

Otherwise you'll have to use "du" as you already discovered (which will be much slower).